# find biggest distance in subset

Tags: graph, maxima

I'm struggling with a real world problem and I can't imagine a non brutforce way to solve it.

I have a (fairly big) list of IP addresses, and a function giving the 'distance' between two addresses.

The problem:

I would like to find N addresses with the highest possible total distance.

The distance function treats the IPv4 addresses as unsigned 32 bits ints and the distance is the positive difference between two addresses.

Any ideas or pointers on how not to have to use an NP complete algo :-) ?

Thanks!

Comment: Is there a way you can sort your distance values?  In excel I would simply sort the list based on distance and take the top N rows.  No excel tag so not sure if that will help yo or not.

Comment: Good idea, n^2 values, which can be sorted in linear time (or quickly anyway), perfect, thanks!